# Running a jQuery function only if specific conditions are true

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div called "testing". This div can appear once or multiple times on the same page with 1 or more  tags inside.  For example, one page could have

```
<div class="testing">
   <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Or another page could have

```
<div class="testing">
   <span>hello</span>
   <span>hello again </span>
</div>
```

I want to run a jQuery function on the "testing" div with the following conditions:

- I only want the function to run if the "testing" div contains more than one span tag.
- I only want the function to run on the "testing" div that contains more than one span tag.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: When you add those spans server-side, simply add a CSS class to the div as well.

Answer (score 2):

Before asking questions, try posting the code you already have. With that said...

```
$('div.testing span').length
```

This will return the number of span elements inside a div with class testing.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your function:

```
if($('.testing span').length > 1) { /* relevant code here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Write your functions
2. Check for the number of spans in testing (hint: `if($('.testing').children('span').length`)
3. Run the respective functions in the "then" portion of your if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if($('.testing span').length > 1) { 

 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would do what the OP is asking.  He needs to do something to each'.testing' div that contains more than one span.  How would you, for example, set the background of each div containing more than one span to red using this code since you don't have a reference to the div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  Replace the portion setting the background to red with whatever you want to do.

```
$(".testing").each(function(index, value) { 
    var spans = $(this).find("span");
    if(spans.length > 1){
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you want are the same, so with 1 condition you could do something like this:

```
if($('.testing span').length > 1) console.log('more than one');
```

**Example with a function**

```
if($('.testing span').length > 1) myFunction();
```